# Negating :LABEL in MATCH clause

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to match nodes that do not have some specific label, like (**I know the below syntax is incorrect**):

```
MATCH (n:Includes:!Excludes)
RETURN n;
```

And I also know I can do this in `WHERE` clause:

```
MATCH (n:Includes)
WHERE NOT n:Excludes
RETURN n;
```

**while the above syntax works** but since <s>the match clause should always be number one choice and</s> I could not find any indication if this is possible or not, I just thought I should ask (at least for the record).

So the question is:

Is it possible to excludes nodes with some label in match clause?

Comment: `since the match clause should always be number one choice ` Where did you found this statement ?

Comment: @ChristopheWillemsen You are right, I made that up but you can find that `MATCH` clause is preferable over `WHERE` clause in [Welcome to the Dark Side: Neo4j Worst Practices (& How to Avoid Them)](https://neo4j.com/blog/dark-side-neo4j-worst-practices/)

Comment: There is strictly no difference between the predicate inside the MATCH or in a WHERE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, as of version 3.1.1 Cypher doesn't have a means of expressing label exclusion in just the MATCH clause.